# How can i delete the content of the table using fluentnhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am using fluent nHibernate for my mappings as follow:

```
public class ContentTagMap: ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Id(t => t.Id);
        Map(t => t.Name);
        HasManyToMany(t => t.Company);
    }
}

public class CompanyMap: ClassMap<Company>
{
    public HelpMap()
    {
        Id(h => h.Id);
        Map(h => h.CompanyName).Length(6000);
        Map(h => h.address).Length(6000);
        HasManyToMany(h => h.Employee);
    }
}
```

These mappings produce Employee Table ,Company Table and EmployeeToCompany Table

**Employee Table**

```
Id    Name
1     John
2     MAX
```

**Company Table**

```
Id    CompanyName   address
1      HTC           ABC
2      HTC2          India
```

**EmployeeToCompany Table**

```
Employee_Id     Company_Id
1               1
2               1
```

How can I delete the employee with Id 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question you should be asking:

#### How can i delete the content of the table using NHibernate?

Fluent NHibernate is only a tool to aid in the mapping of your entities.  **NHibernate** is what you use to create, read, update and delete data.  In any event:

> 9.5. Deleting persistent objects
>
> ISession.Delete() will remove an object's state from the database. Of
>   course, your application might still hold a reference to it. So it's
>   best to think of Delete() as making a persistent instance transient.

From the [NHibernate Documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-deleting)

You probably want to also define a Cascading style on your many to many relationship (`HasManyToMany`) in your mapping.

If you use `Cascade.SaveUpdate` in your many to many whenever you delete an entity on one side of the relationship it will delete that entity and any relationships. If you remove the association (ex. if you removed an `Employee` from a `Company`) it will only delete the relationship (`EmployeeToCompany`). This is what I've typically found to work in the case of many to many relationships.

Look at this article for more details on mapping and using a many to many relationship in Fluent NHibernate.

[how to keep many to many relationships in sync with nhibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090918/how-to-keep-many-to-many-relationships-in-sync-with-nhibernate/10098851#10098851)